# How do we play multiplayer minecraft on iPads?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

We have two iPads, and both of them have Minecraft PE. My son wants to connect the two and play with me. I have absolutely no idea what I am doing here, so I do not know how to do this.

One game says "Broadcast to LAN", and the other one says "Local Server Multiplayer". I have switched both to on.

What do I need to do to be able to play joined? We are both on the same WiFi.

Comment: Are you both on the same version? (Should say version at the bottom left of the title screen)

Comment: thank you, no we are not :P one is v0,12,2 alpha, and the other one is v0,12,3 alpha. Do I just update his then?

Comment: You'll need to update the one currently on 0.12.2, yep.

Comment: ok, done, thank you! What do I do now? Sorry, I have no clue! He made a new world, how do I find it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Ensure :**

- You need to have Minecraft with the same version
- You need to have the iPad connected to the same Wi-Fi
- You need to have `Broadcast to LAN` turned on

**Initiating**

1. Load up your world on one of your iPad and turn `Broadcast to Lan` on
2. On the other iPad, click play and you should see the World name in the very bottom of the world selection menu including the hosting iPad IP. Click it to join

**Doesn't work? Restart your iPad!**

Comment: Thank you, done everything you mention, but I am not able to find his world? It is not listed on my screen

Comment: In the settings, there should be an option to turn on Lan. Did you turn that on? I forgot to mention that into the answer

Comment: yes, both are on :) I have tried to go out of the game and back too, but I still do not get his on mine

Comment: Hold on a second! I'm testing things out. By normal, this should connect you both.

Comment: ok, thank you very much! I scroll down the list, and the name he made to his new world is not on the list. Does it need to be an old world?

Comment: @user128631 Make sure that the first user is still in the world you want to play on when the second user looks at the world selection list.

Comment: he is playing the game right now, and I am trying to find him, but it does not show on my screen

Comment: Same version, same Wi-fi and `Broadcast to Lan` on? Double check things out!

Comment: double checked, and everything is correct. It is same wifi, same update on the game, and both are on broadcast to LAN, and I still can not find his game

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I can't help you. I'm sorry. You can check this for what it supposed to do [Click me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElckEBo4frU)

Comment: Thank you very much guys :) I figured it out! We had to turn the iPads' completely off, and restart, and now we are happy to go :)

Comment: Oh well. Normally, it doesn't need restart. But it will do! Don't forget tag this as a correct answer!

Comment: Don't know how to do that, but I will do my best. Thanks!

Comment: There should be a check mark on the left of my answer. Clicking it will mark my answer as a correct answer. Anywho, just ask more question if needed and answer if you know for sure!

Comment: A restart did the trick for us as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. The problem was my router.. I had to enable a wifi guestzone, in the routers settings.. BTW the router is a DLINK DIR-865L.. I had 2 wifi connections, one 2.4 GHz and one 5 GHz connection.. NONE WORKED.. But when I enabled the guestzone, the 2 ipads found each other immediatly, when they both were connected on the guestzone wifi link.. Wich my router called dlink-guest.. Woked like a charm.. ;-)

Comment: I've seen a few flags on this question, and just want to remind folks that anything which [attempts to answer the question is an answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8357/8350). If you think it's a poor answer then downvote it, but don't flag it for deletion.