# Minecraft Pe on two iPads, unable to connect

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have this strange issue where I want to play with my son and we can not connect the two together.

So my son with a newer iPad starts up Minecraft and launches into his world. Then I press play and wait for his world to show up.

This often works and often doesn't.

When it doesn't we both shut down Minecraft (double tap on the home button and swipe Minecraft up). Then when we start Minecraft up again, sometimes we are lucky and his world shows up. Sometimes it doesn't and we are not happy (like right now).

When I then attempt to use airdrop, I can actually see his iPad show up and send something, so I know the two devices can communicate over the wifi network.

How can I get this to work reliably?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I'm going to walk you through the troubleshooting process step by step.

**Step 1**

Check and make sure that both of you have the "Broadcast to Lan" option switched ON.

**Step 2**

Make sure that your wifi is functioning correctly. Double check that both of your devices are connected to the same wifi and make sure BOTH of you attempt to host the game. Also, make sure that both iPads are running on the same Time Zone.

**Step 3**

Also make sure that both of you have the same version of Minecraft PE, if you both have even slightly different versions of Minecraft then it is likely for them to not connect.

Alright, now I'm going to tell you how it should work, if you repeat this every time then it should work consistently.

1. Have one game (the host) load up minecraft and ensure that they have "Broadcast to Lan" enabled. Make sure the host is inside the desired world.
2. On the other (Non-hot) iPad, select play and the other player's world (or hosting IP) will show up in separate colored text. Select that world and enjoy playing together.

If problems persist then refer to this [page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241662/how-do-we-play-multiplayer-minecraft-on-ipads?rq=1).

If none of this helps go ahead and try to delete and re-install Minecraft on one or both of your iPads. And if it still does not work reliably after all of that then it is likely that your games/iPads have been tampered with in the past. Hope this helped.

Comment: As a last attempt, I restarted the older (non-host) iPad and then I was able to connect. Like [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241662/how-do-we-play-multiplayer-minecraft-on-ipads?rq=1) also states. But as I can see his Ipad via AirDrop, this feels like a Minecraft PE bug.