# How do me and my friends join each other's worlds on iPhone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We are all on the same wi-fi in the same room. And we all have the same version of minecraft. We press play and it won't show that we have any friends playing.

Comment: you have to open to lan, or basically let other people join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we play multiplayer minecraft on iPads?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241662/how-do-we-play-multiplayer-minecraft-on-ipads)